# Mysql 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE' specify column's value depending on file

Tags: java, mysql, load-data-infile

I am stuck in a situation where I have to read data from 3 separate large CSV files and store it in MySQL database.

csv file columns:

> total_rev,monthly_rev,day_rev

Database table's columns:

> total_rev, monthly_rev, day_rev, from

I am able to insert data in my table by using following query:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/datauser/Desktop/working/revenue_2016_10_06.csv'  
INTO TABLE revenue_table  
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','   
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  
(total_rev,monthly_rev,day_rev);
```

But I am stuck in a situation where I want to add hard coded parameter in the "Load Data Local" query to add **from**'s value depending upon the file.

so at the end my table will contain records like:

```
total_rev, monthly_rev, day_rev,  from
  11,       222,          333,    file1
  22,        32,          343,    file1
  11,        22,          333,    file1
  11,        22,           33,    file22
  11,        22,           33,    file22
```

How can I specify this file1, file22 value's in above query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `SET` clause to the LOAD DATA statement, to assign a value to the (unfortunately named) `from` column:

```
 LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/datauser/Desktop/working/revenue_2016_10_06.csv'  
 INTO TABLE revenue_table  
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','   
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  
 (total_rev,monthly_rev,day_rev)

 SET `from` = 'file1'
 ;
```

---

Note that it's also possible to load the fields from the file into user-defined variables and/or reference user-defined variables in the SET clause.

```
 SET @file_name = 'myfilename'
 ;

 LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/datauser/Desktop/working/revenue_2016_10_06.csv'  
 INTO TABLE revenue_table  
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','   
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  
 ( @total_rev
 , @monthly_rev
 , @day_rev
 )
 SET `total_rev`   = @total_rev
   , `monthly_rev` = @monthly_rev
   , `day_rev`     = @day_rev
   , `from`        = @file_name
 ;
```

If we had fields in the file we want to skip, not load into the table, we can use a user-defined variable as a placeholder. We can also use expressions in the SET clause, which allows us to leverage some very useful MySQL functions for some manipulation... IFNULL, NULLIF, STR_TO_DATE, CONCAT, etc.

Comment: Is this possible to use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE @file_name ` syntax?

Comment: @hriziya:  i don't think that's a valid usage of a user-defined variable;  a udv can supply a a *value* in a SQL statement; a udv can not supply n *identifier* (like a table name or column name) or a *keyword* (like FROM or ASC).   We could give it a whirl and see what MySQL does if we use a user-defined variable in place of the file location. (I suspect we'll get an error, but maybe it will work.)

Comment: Thanks, Yes, I tried that already, and got an error when I tried to supply variable as filename