# How do I write a query in MYSQL to avoid qoutes from a CSV

Tags: mysql, csv, import-from-excel

I have a big .csv with over a million lines that I am trying to import into MYSQL

an example of a line is as follows: 50778,2020-04-26,f,"$2,655.00","$2,655.00",5,1125
This represents 7 fields: id, date, availability, price, adjustedPrice, minNights, maxNights.

I am having problems reading even one of them into a table with the correct columns and parameters for each

This is the query used to import:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads/calendar.csv'
INTO TABLE calendar
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
```

Right now I am getting data too long for column price at row 1

The table is:

```sql
CREATE TABLE calendar ( 
 listing_id varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 date date NOT NULL,
 available varchar(1) NOT NULL,
 price varchar(25) NOT NULL,
 adjusted_price varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 minimum_nights int(11) NOT NULL,
 maximum_nights int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (listing_i`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

See that price and adjusted price are varchars because they contain "$"

Comment: how is your table. further you need to a line terminated by `\n\r` and what know is missing see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39918792/5193536

Comment: I have updated my question with an image of the table. My problem right now is in the price parameter.

Comment: in mysql 8.0.23 it works like a charme

Comment: Have you got an error whe updating to 8.0.23? I have seen some people including myself getting this error: Target host is configured as windows but seems to be a different OS.

Comment: you havt to follow the upgrade instrucions on  mysql home page, but you firrst can try to update to 5.7.32 also ythe problem can simply not be in that line. my csv had only this line without heade

Comment: I feel like being almost there. This is my current error LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.7\\Uploads\\test.csv' INTO TABLE calendar  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' Error Code: 1366. Incorrect integer value: '"50778' for column 'listing_id' at row 1 . The problem is that it tries to enclose every value with "

Comment: use bigint for your tables and not int(11)